# Не работает алгоритм замены символов в строке

Tags: python, строки, replace

Задача: пользователь вводит текст из букв и символов, нужно вывести список состоящий из слов без лишних символов.

```
text = str(input('Введите текст:\t'))
list_text = text.split(' ')
for i in list_text:
    for j in i:
        if not j.isalpha():
            i = i.replace(j, '')
print(list_text)
```

Не могу понять почему в этом коде не работает цикл замены символов на ""? символы просто остаются на своих местах вместо замены.
При том что цикл начиная с for j in i отдельно от основного кода работает без вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

так как вы не сохраняете измененный символ в список

```py
text = str(input('Введите текст:\t'))
list_text = text.split(' ')
for i in range(len(list_text)):
    for j in list_text[i]:
        if not j.isalpha():
            list_text[i] = list_text[i].replace(j, '')
print(list_text)
```

код не проверял, но должен работать

Comment: нет, не будет работать, так как у вас после замены ```j``` на пустую строку, получается что следующий  ```j``` в цикле будет не следующим, а следующим следующим, это очень распространенная ошибка, в итоге будет ```IndexError```. Чтобы прошло без ошибок, вам надо все изменения сохранять в новый массив строк, а старый не изменять, НИКАК.

Comment: Спасибо. Как ни странно, но у меня этот код работает без ошибок

Comment: Боюсь что нет, можно провести эксперимент 
https://pastebin.com/5E1eAHaX
это будет бесконечный цикл.
`IndexError` был бы справедлив есть использовать цикл вида `for i in range(len(lst)):` 

можно попробовать разобраться получше запустив `python3 -m dis main.py`

Answer (score 0):

Строка не изменяется, так как вы в цикле присваиваете к `i` строку, во втором цикле вы присваиваете к `j` символ из этой строки, поэтому, когда вы изменяете символ `i = i.replace(j, '')`, вы изменяете не исходную строку, вы изменяете новую строку `j`, которую вы создали в цикле. Для изменения исходной строки вам надо перебирать не элементы строки, а индексы.

```py
alphabet = “abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz”
text = input('Введите текст:\t')
list_text = text.split()
new_list_text = [""]*len(list_text)

for i in range(len(list_text)):
    for j in range(len(list_text[i])):
        if not list_text[i][j].lower() in alphabet:
            new_list_text[i] = list_text[i][:j] + list_text[i][j+1:]

        else:
            new_list_text[i] = list_text[i]

print(new_list_text)
```

Comment: Спасибо, упустил момент что изменяю переменную, а не содержание индекса

Comment: ничего, со всеми бывает)

Comment: Что-то не так, код не работает, не происходит удаления символов, вернее удаляется только последний символ каждой строки из коллекции если он не буква